# How total is calculated in search resolve in marklogic

Tags: java, marklogic

In the MarkLogic example explained in this article https://docs.marklogic.com/search:parse, how the total is calculated?

example :

```
<search:response total="1234" start="1" page-length="10" xmlns=""
            xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
```

Comment: You mean the example in https://docs.marklogic.com/search:search right?

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a search with [`search:search`](https://docs.marklogic.com/search:search) it executes an [unfiltered search](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_89797) with the provided search criteria.

The `@total` that is returned is the equivalent of what you would get if you provided the search criteria to [`xdmp:estimate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:estimate). It uses the indexes to answer your question and tell you how many documents it thinks match.

Comment: Close.  It's actually cts:remainder.  See the section at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_98851 .  This matters as you go through pages.  https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:remainder

Comment: Also, are you sure it's unfiltered?  I couldn't find a definite answer.  If it is unfiltered then @total would always be correct, right?

Comment: Yes. It is mentioned in the https://docs.marklogic.com/search:search Usage Notes: "The output of `search:search` returns a `<response>` element, which in turn contains a `total` attribute. The value of the `total` attribute is an estimate, based on the index resolution of the query, and it is not filtered for accuracy. The accuracy of the index resolution depends on the index configuration of the database, on the query, and on the data being searched."

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you are saying, the estimate  remainder is unfiltered.  But not (by default) the actual search itself.